# JavaFx setText the field as an int

Tags: java, javafx

How can I set a textfield as a int type?
Like if i had this line of code:
`appointmentText.setText(pa.getindex());`

if `appointmentText` is the textField and `pa.getindex();` gets an int type from another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf()`

```
appointmentText.setText(String.valueOf(pa.getindex());
```

By the way, `getindex()` should be `getIndex()` following the camel-case naming convention.

Comment: oh wow no errors in the code finally, thanks!!!

Comment: @mccob try accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign an `Integer` to any `String` directly. You should change `Integer` to `String` type First. then you can Assign this as a `String`.

```
 appointmentText.setText(pa.getindex().toString());// try this
```